# How to quickly multiply a list of matrices by a list of vectors?

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector

I have a `(13*122) x (14)` matrix (122 stacked 13x14's), which I made into a list of 122 individual `13 x 14` matrices.

```
set.seed(1)

mat = matrix(rnorm(13*122*14,0,1),(13*122),14)
```

I have another matrix that is `122 x 14`.

```
beta = matrix(rnorm(122*14,0,1),122,14)
```

I want to multiply each stacked matrix by the correspond row in beta, so the first `13 x 14` matrix would get multiplied by `beta[1,]` (which is `14x1`), so I'd get `13x1` matrix, etc.

Should I do this with a list or is it unnecessary?  I would like it to be as fast as possible.

I want to return a `13 x 122` matrix.

Comment: Do you need to multiply each element of `lst <- lapply(split(1:nrow(mat),(1:nrow(mat)-1) %/%13+1), function(i) mat[i,])` by each row of `beta`?  Perhaps `Map(`*`, lst, split(beta, row(beta)))`

Comment: Yea, where each element, call it Y, is like lst[[i]]%*%beta[i,], but if there is a way to do this without making lst, that would be good too. Thank you for your help

Comment: Without creating a list, you can change the dimensions to an array and then do the calculation in a loop, I guess it should be fast.  Updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `split` the matrix into a 'list' of length '122' and use `mapply` to do the `%*%` of corresponding elements of 'lst' and rows of 'beta'

```
lst <- lapply(split(1:nrow(mat),(1:nrow(mat)-1) %/%13+1),
                        function(i) mat[i,])
res <- mapply(`%*%`, lst, split(beta, row(beta)))
dim(res)
#[1]  13 122
```

Or we could convert the `matrix` to `array` and then do the multiplication, which I guess would be fast

```
mat1 <- mat #if we need a copy of the original matrix 
dim(mat1) <- c(13, 122, 14)
mat2 <- aperm(mat1, c(1,3,2))
res2 <- matrix(, ncol=122, nrow=13)
for(i in 1:(dim(mat2)[3])){
  res2[,i] <- mat2[,,i] %*%beta[i,]
}

all.equal(res, res2, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Ok, Sorry, yeah each element is a dataframe, let me convert to matrix!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mat <- lapply(1:122, function(x) matrix(data = rnorm(13*14,0,1), nrow = 13, ncol = 14))

mat2 <- lapply(1:122, function(x) mat[[x]] %*% beta[x,])
```

Answer (score 0):

look for the book introduction to algorithms and look at page 331. There is a pseodu algortihm to do so. you have to make a three of matrix products where it will sort it so that it will be an optimum for multiplication but short hand, if you have three matrices M1 of m x n, M2 of n x v, M3 of v x w then you wish to know if (M1 * M2) * M3 or M1 * (M2 * M3) is better the answer is to calculate the to numbers m*n*v and n*v*w and deside which is biggest. the smallest one is always better.